# onBeforeSendEmail event triggered from Commerce_EmailsService

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, events

I'm trying to access the `order` and `orderHistory` model via `onBeforeSendEmail` event. I can see that in `Commerce_EmailsService.php` file on line 311 the event is created with those params and passed to `onBeforeSendEmail`, but when I try to access them from my plugin, they are not there. I thought they would be available in the `variables` param, but they are not (or I'm doing something wrong here).

Does anyone know if/how I can access those models from `onBeforeSendEmail` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show what code you're trying to use to access the parameters, but something like this should work from your main plugin class:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    craft()->on('commerce_emails.beforeSendEmail', function($event) {
        $params = $event->params;

        $craftEmail = $params['craftEmail'];
        $commerceEmail = $params['commerceEmail'];
        $order = $params['order'];
        $orderHistory = $params['orderHistory'];

        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Brad, turns out I was looking at the basic emails event `email.onBeforeSendEmail` and not the one for commerce `commerce_emails.beforeSendEmail` (which by the way is not listed on the events reference page: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference). Thanks again Brad.